# Using .loc doesn't make SettingWithCopyWarning disappear in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, warnings

```
import pandas as pd
cars = pd.read_csv('car_sales.csv')
cars_new = cars.dropna()
for item in ['mileage', 'engine', 'max_power']:
  cars_new[item] = cars_new[item].apply(lambda text: float(text.split()[0]))
```

The code above (which uses [this dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/nehalbirla/vehicle-dataset-from-cardekho)) code gives me

> /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:1773: SettingWithCopyWarning:
> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
> Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

I tried using `cars_new.loc[:,item]` instead of `cars_new[item]` but this didn't help. How can I get rid of this warning then?

Comment: For one thing, it can make things easier to use the built-in series.str methods instead of apply for simple operations like this `cars_new[item].str.split().str[0].astype(float)` Although it would be helpful if you would [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with a sample of your input and your expected output in the body of the question, not as an external link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you have is that you're creating a shallow copy of the data-frame `cars` and setting it to `cars_new`. There are two possible solutions to this problem:

```
import pandas as pd
cars = pd.read_csv('car_sales.csv')
cars_new = cars.dropna().copy()
for item in ['mileage', 'engine', 'max_power']:
  cars_new[item] = cars_new[item].apply(lambda text: float(text.split()[0]))
```

Using the [copy](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html) functionality by default creates a deep copy of the data-frame. Another way to do this is getting rid of the `cars_new` variable:

```
import pandas as pd
cars = pd.read_csv('car_sales.csv')
cars = cars.dropna()
for item in ['mileage', 'engine', 'max_power']:
  cars [item] = cars [item].apply(lambda text: float(text.split()[0]))
```

Comment: you are right! I've deleted my comment and upvoted your answer.